# Approach to parse XML and store data

Tags: java, xml, excel

I am trying to parse an XML with 35000+ items using a SAX parser:
Each item will have attributes like

```
<ValueGroup AttributeID="AAA">
      <Value QualifierID="Q1">2016-21-7 05:08:09</Value>
      <Value QualifierID="Q2">2016-21-6 23:31:52</Value>
 </ValueGroup>
```

I will have to create separate excels based on the qualifier IDs. 
At the same time there are attributes which will be common to both the excels.

```
<Value AttributeID="BBB">Trade articles</Value>
```

I could have multiple such qualifiers and I have 300 attributes for each item.
I am planning to use Apache POI for creating the excel.

Possible options I am thinking of are:

> 1. Have separate list of objects for each qualifier. Create a POJO with all the attributes and set the values as and when I parse the XML.
> 2. Have separate list of hashmaps for each qualifier. Add the attributes as key value pairs in a hashmap. This way I will have a
>    hashmap for each item.

The problem with both these approaches is that I am basically duplicating the common values also. Also, if the number of items becomes huge I could eat up a lot of memory.

> 3. Another option I thought of is to store the attribute and values in a JSON notation and store it in a file thereby not having to keep all the data in memory
> 4. Variant of option 1. Create a list of POJOs with all the attributes but the difference is the attributes with multiple qualifiers will be a hashmap with key as qualifier and the value being the corresponding value from XML. This way I will not be duplicating the information in multiple lists

Is there any better way of doing this(there should be) or improving this?
I am thinking of going with Option 3.

**Edit : Improved option 1a to option 4 with additional clarity**